# jQuery - Calling .change(); in javascript code does not fire

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, asp.net-mvc-4

In this question, all code has been generalized.
As the question title has explained, I have a jQuery function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (something) {
       // This does something
    } else if (something else) {
       // This does something else
    } else { 
       // And this does something else
    }
});
```

In this function, when the page loads, it checks for information that's on the web page.
I have a hidden input with a value that I check. This works. 
I have 2 Drop down lists with two IDs (for the sake of argument): ddl1, ddl2

In MVC 4, they will look like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedValue, Model.List1, new { id = "ddl1" })
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedValue, Model.List2, new { id = "ddl2" })
```

Next, I have two On Change jQuery methods, accordingly:

```
$("#ddl1").change(function () {
     // Does something when the index of the first drop down changes
});

$("#ddl2").change(function () {
    // Does something when the index of the second drop down changes
});
```

When I change the index on the page, these methods fire.
Now, Here's where my question comes into play.

In my `$(document).ready()` function, I call those On Change function from this method, it does not fire...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (something) {
       if (condition for ddl1) {
          $("#ddl1").change(); // Does not fire.
       } else {
          $("#ddl2").change(); // Does not fire.
       }
    } else if (something else) {
       // This does something else
    } else { 
       // And this does something else
    }
});
```

To me, this makes no sense why those functions are not firing.
It's a direct method call.
If someone can shed some light on this matter, i'll be thankful.

Cheers.

Comment: are change events also in _document.ready_???

Comment: No sir, they are not. Should I add <code>$(function() {});</code> around my on change methods?

Comment: if I had to guess it is a timing issue.  Try moving those change calls to a button click event and click the button after the page loads.  See if they fire then

Comment: Curious, if I already have a document.ready function being called, wouldn't that mean all functions should be ready? That function is only called when the DOM is ready. Correct?

Comment: Are you sure the code branch that calls `.change()` is being executed? Add `console.log()` statements to verify.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I modified my code to do the following (I went with just plain javascript, since I don't have the time to figure out why this is an issue):

1) I removed my on change jQuery method to a plain javascript function:
From:

```
$("#ddl1").change(function () { /*code*/ });
```

To:

```
function changeDdl1 () { /*code*/ }
```

2) I took out the triggers to simply add a javascript call:
From:

```
$("#ddl1").trigger("change");
```

To:

```
changeDdl1();
```

3) I added the @onchange MVC 4 attribute to my Drop Down Lists:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedValue, Model.List1,
                      new { id = "ddl1", @onchange = "changeDdl1();"})
```

Thank you everyone who has provided help and hints.

Cheers.

Answer (score -1):

The proper way to trigger a change method using jQuery, is using trigger function, this way:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if (something) {
   if (condition for ddl1) {
      $("#ddl1").trigger("change"); // TRIGGER change event
   } else {
      $("#ddl2").trigger("change"); // TRIGGER change event
   }
  } else if (something else) {
   // This does something else
  } else { 
   // And this does something else
  }
});
```

More info here: http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Comment: I am currently using that method call in my code.
I am also using '$("#ddl1").on("change", function() {});'
It still does not fire. I am puzzled, to say the least.

Comment: `jquery.fn.change` calls `.trigger('change')`. Functionally, there's no difference.